# how can we display data from database for all field form custom table in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

i have created one table which is name with ***example*** which have filed like ***firstname, last name, email***. now i display data through

**\app\design\frontend\default\example_theme\layout\nextbits_example.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<layout version="0.1.0">

<example_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="example/example" template="example/email2.phtml"/>
        <block type="example/example" template="catalog/nextbits_example.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    </example_index_index>

</layout>
```

**\app\design\frontend\default\example_theme\template\catalog\nextbits_example.phtml**

```
<div>
    <?php
        echo $this->getContent(); //disp emaill call method from block example
    ?>
</div>
```

**\app\code\local\Xyz\Example\Block\Example.php**

```
<?php
class NextBits_Example_Block_Example extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function getContent()
    {
        $model = Mage::getModel('example/example')->load('1');
        $data = $model->getData();


        $model = Mage::getModel('example/example')->getCollection();

        echo '<pre>';


        foreach($model as $obj){
            print_R($obj->getData('fname'));
            echo "<br>";
        }  
    }

}
```

its output is only for one field suppose i get either email, or first name or lastname , 
**Now if i want to display result of all the field , How can i get result of all field?**

**and also want only list of result filed wise like all id, then all the firstname and then all lastname like this..then what to do?**

Thank You.!!!

Comment: Try `$obj->getData()`, without any parameters.

Comment: @Marius  no it not works.

Comment: @Marius it shows like as below

`Array
(
    [example_id] => 1
    [fname] => fname
    [lname] => lname
    [email] => fnanmelname@fl.com
    [date] => 
)`

Comment: wasn't that your question? you wanted all the fields, right?

Comment: @Marius ya its true. but, is this the only way to display all field? Can't we display any other way?

Comment: it also show me written Array, i guess it should not be there. what you say?

Comment: just loop through the array. What more do you want?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9554/discussion-between-michel06-and-marius)

Comment: I left a reply on chat for you.

Comment: @Marius Thank You Brother...Thank You Very Much.....
its Successful
Please put your answer here ill choose it as correct answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('example/example')->getCollection();
$keys = array_keys($collection->getFirstItem()->getData());
```

now you have the you need.

```
foreach ($keys as $key){ // loop through all the keys (fname, lname, email... 
    foreach ($collection as $obj){//loop throught each object 
        print_r($obj->getData($key));//get the value for a speficic key. 
    } 
}
```

Comment: A note here: This line $keys = array_keys($collection->getFirstItem()->getData()); only works when there is at least 1 existing row in table